# Android: Performance and memory used when loading icon from resources

Tags: android, performance, resources

### Load icons from resources during execution VS keep resources loaded in memory

I have 8 icon files with arrows. I'm using them to show moving direction during GPS tracking.

Which way is better for performance and memory allocations - keep them in memory for use or read them from resources every time?

Answer (score 0):

you would use a drawable which can hold a set of drawables you can switch through,
 this one: [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html)